# How can registration controller login user with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails application that uses Devise for user authentication.  If a user registers using the registration form, but he happens to use an existing valid username/password, instead of giving an error, I want to just log in the user.  But I can't figure out how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the devise RegistrationsController create action. After the regular registration code, you will need to add your code to check if a user already exists and sign in if the email/pass combination match. Something like this (based on the devise version you are using - this is based on the source of 2.2.4)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      def create
        build_resource

        if resource.save
          if resource.active_for_authentication?
            set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
            sign_up(resource_name, resource)
            respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          else
            set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
            expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
            respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          end
        else
          # Add code to check if user exists and sign in
          # I am just pasting in the sign_in code here and you will need to customize it as per your needs
          # You can directly use params and User model, or try an keep your code generic
          self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
          set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
          sign_in(resource_name, resource)
          respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        end
      end
end
```

And add the controller to your routes as well:

`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations"}`